# CHECK constraint does not return the same as the called functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm setting up an auction website for a school project, and I have to make a CHECK constraint that checks whether a bid is valid. The CHECK constraint calls three functions:
- fn_getHighestBid returns the highest bid on this item.
- fn_getMinimumRaise returns the minimum value between the current highest bid and the bid that is being inserted.
- fn_isValidBid checks both of the above two functions and returns whether a bid can be inserted.

When I use SELECT to get the results of the functions, they return the expected result. But when I try to insert something into the table, it violates the CHECK constraint.

I've tried adding WITH CHECK to the query that adds the constraint to the database, but that didn't change anything.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_getHighestBid (@Item BIGINT)
RETURNS NUMERIC(10, 2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @highestBid NUMERIC(10, 2) = 0
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bid WHERE Item = @Item) = 0 -- Checks whether there are any bids for this auctioned item.
    SET @highestBid = (SELECT Startingprice FROM Item WHERE ItemID = @Item)
    ELSE SET @highestBid = (SELECT MAX(BidValue) FROM Bid WHERE Item = @Item)

    RETURN @highestBid
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_getMinimumRaise (@Item BIGINT)
RETURNS NUMERIC(10, 2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @minimumRaise NUMERIC(10, 2) = 0
    DECLARE @highestBid NUMERIC(10, 2) = dbo.fn_getHighestBid(@Item)


    SET @minimumRaise = CASE
    WHEN @highestBid BETWEEN 1.00 AND 49.99 THEN 0.50
    WHEN @highestBid BETWEEN 49.99 AND 499.99 THEN 1.00
    WHEN @highestBid BETWEEN 500.00 AND 999.99 THEN 5.00
    WHEN @highestBid BETWEEN 1000.00 AND 4999.99 THEN 10.00
    WHEN @highestBid >= 5000.00 THEN 50.00
    ELSE 0.00
    END

    RETURN @minimumRaise
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_isValidBid (@Item BIGINT, @BidValue NUMERIC(10, 2))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @minimumRaise NUMERIC(10, 2) = dbo.fn_getMinimumRaise(@Item)
    DECLARE @highestBid NUMERIC(10, 2) = dbo.fn_getHighestBid(@Item)

    IF @BidValue >= (@highestBid + @minimumRaise) RETURN 1

    RETURN 0
END
```

The constraint is as follows:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Bid
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Bid_BidValue
CHECK (dbo.fn_isValidBid(Item, BidValue) = 1)
GO
```

There is a test item in the Item table, with these (relevant) columns:

ItemID = 1
Startprice = 50.00

The following query:

```sql
SELECT dbo.fn_getHighestBid(1), dbo.fn_getMinimumRaise(1), dbo.fn_isValidBid(1, 51.00)
```

It returns 50.00, 1.00 and 1 (as expected).
But when I try to insert a bid using this INSERT:

```sql
INSERT INTO Bid (Item, BidValue, User) VALUES (1, 51.00, 'TestUser2') -- TestUser2 is the user that places the bid.
```

It returns error message:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_Bid_BidValue". The conflict occurred in database "testdatabase", table "dbo.Bid".

The table Bid has the following columns:
- Item, which is a FK reference to the Item table.
- BidValue, the value of the bid.
- User, the user that placed the bid.
- BidDay, the day on which the bid was placed.
- BidTime, the timestamp.

Comment: Because `51.00 <> 52.00`?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you check (and post in your question) the structure of the `Bid` table, and especially its CHECK constraints? Does the table have any other related objects that might affect the insert behavior (like triggers)?

Comment: @Larnu The minimum bid should be 51.00, so 52.00 should be valid.

Comment: My point is that you're testing one value, but inserting another; so the test isn't comparable.. Without the DDL of the table, we can't comment any further.

Comment: Inserting 51.00 returns the same result, so I editted the question accordingly.

Comment: @BartHofland The table has a CHECK constraint that checks whether the bid is not from the seller himself. I editted the question to show the structure of the Bid table.

Comment: The `CHECK` logically runs *after* the row is inserted but *before* it is committed, so it will always fail, as the check does not exclude the very bid we just inserted. This is not something you should do with a `CHECK` constraint at all; such a constraint should logically always depend only on the state of a single row and not become invalidated if new rows are inserted. Breaking this rule can lead to all sorts of nasty side effects, since the engine assumes it will hold. Use a stored procedure or trigger to implement this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using user-defined functions within CHECK constraints is problematic. For example, look at:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cdb87a2e-41ce-4a97-8a14-3f218eb00721/function-check-constraint-ignored?forum=transactsql
- http://www.librement-votre.fr/shaarli/?x6gyTg
- https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/another-hidden-parallelism-killer-scalar-udfs-check-constraints/

Perhaps you could replace the CHECK constraint with a trigger. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_Bid_insert]
ON [dbo].[Bid]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE [dbo].[fn_isValidBid] ([Item], [BidValue]) = 0) BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Attempting to insert invalid bid.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Hello Bart, this trigger works for checking the constraint, thank you. However, because this is an INSTEAD OF trigger, even valid insertions get cancelled. Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by adding:
```
ELSE BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Bid] SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END;
```

Comment: Oh. Yes, I see. I have been experimenting with INSTEAD OF and FOR/AFTER and I overlooked it in my answer. Sorry about that. I'm happy you could fix it by adding an INSERT query.

Comment: I have tried to avoid adding an INSERT query, however, because if your table would have an IDENTITY column, all columns had to be specified explicitly in the INSERT query. And that would make the trigger completely dependent on the table structure.

Comment: But I cannot get it to work correctly in a FOR/AFTER trigger, because the record is already inserted when the trigger is executing, causing your UDFs to return false negatives. :-( So I personally would not use such trigger logic at all. Using a stored procedure might result in less headaches.